# Changing qml application language on runtime depending user select

Tags: qt, qml, multilingual

I want to implement functionality like in web site. There will be 3 buttons. Each of them identify application language. By default application will show text on English. Then user can select appropriate language and the interface will change automatically.

Application is QML based.

I make some research, but unfortunatly not successfull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML).

In qml you have to do then somehting like this:

```
    Text{
    text:qsTr('14:Start 5x erfolglos')
}
```

You wrap text with qsTr so that you translate with linguist look [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Quick_guide_to_add_multilanguage_support_to_your_QML_application)

You still have to do something with c++ but it is just copy paste and change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I get the same answer on of. site forum. Made a little modification of my code and now it is working.